# VBA Code to stop another VBA based on date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA that creates a copy of selected sheet(s) in a new workbook

```
Public Sub CopySelectedSheets()
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy
End Sub
```

I wanted this to stop running when a date has passed,

so got this code

```
Dim stopDate As Date
stopDate = Sheets("Org. & Staff Basic Data").Range("C19").Value
If Date >= stopDate Then
   MsgBox "This code cannot be executed after " & stopDate
   Exit Sub
End If

Public Sub CopySelectedSheets()
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy
End Sub
```

but when I run it error compile highlight "C19"

Comment: Is your new code in a sub? You should put that code before the copying.

Comment: All code must be in functions, sub-routines or declarations which start with a name and usually have a clear "End", like `End Sub` or `End Function`. Within the limits of such procedures no further sub, functions or declarations can be placed. So, if the code you published is part of a procedure it fails because it contains the Sub `CopySelectedSheet`. And if it isn't within a procedure it fails because its code isn't within a procedure. Move `Public Sub CopySelectedSheet` to the very top of your sample code, leaving all other liens where they are.

Answer (score 1):

Your request doesn't make much sense; what you need to do is modify the CopySelectedSheets sub so that it does its job as you want

```
Public Sub CopySelectedSheets()

    Dim Sh As WorkSheet
    Dim stopDate As Date
    
    stopDate = Sheets("Org. & Staff Basic Data").Range("C19").Value
    For Each Sh In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        If Date >= stopDate Then
           MsgBox "This code cannot be executed after " & stopDate
           Exit For
        Else
            Sh.Copy
        End If
    Next Sh

End Sub
```